# ternary plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I am trying to make a ternary plot in R using the package ggtern.

I have two different ternary plots that i want to combine in one plot in a way that they are on top of each other. please see them in the attached picture.

[image: pic 1 and 2]

I want to combine them something like this:

[image: combined pic]

my codes for making these two plots are here.

```
# ternary density plot
comp.raw_data = data.frame((clo(comp.raw,total=100)), bp)
(plot <- ggtern(data = comp.raw_data, aes(x = sed, y = stand, z = walk)))
plot +
  stat_density_tern(geom = "polygon", n=200, contour = TRUE, 
                    aes(fill=..level.., alpha=..level..))+
  theme_custom(tern.panel.background = "white", 
               tern.plot.background = NULL, 
               col.T = "black", col.L = "black", col.R = "black", 
               col.grid.minor = NULL) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = " light green", high="dark green")+
  guides(color="none", fill="none", alpha="none")

# ternary plot 2. 
plot <- ggtern(data = work, aes(x = sed, y = stand, z = walk)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill = "bp", size=bp),
             shape = 21) + 
  labs(fill = "bp"))
(plot1_grouplevel = plot + 
  theme_custom(tern.panel.background = "white", 
               tern.plot.background = NULL, 
               col.T = "black", col.L = "black", col.R = "black", 
               col.grid.minor = NULL) )
```

can somebody help?

Comment: I might recommend taking a look at Section 5.2 [Elkins and Grove properties] in this paper about ggtern: https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v087c03/v87c03.pdf. There's an example with code that overlays points on a ternary plot with densities.